# How does map2SpatialLines work in the maptools library?

Tags: r, coordinates, geospatial

In the [maptools](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/maptools/index.html) library, there is a function that converts a map from the [map](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/maps/index.html) library to a SpatialLine object. For example:

```
library(maptools)
library(maps)
usa <- map('usa')
llCRS <- CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84")
wrld_sp <- map2SpatialLines(usa, proj4string = llCRS)
```

However, the map `usa` is a bit peculiar in the sense that it doesn't describe each set of lines separately. Instead, it seems to clump everything together in coordinates `x` and `y`:

```
> str(usa)
List of 4
 $ x    : num [1:381] -101.4 -100.6 -99.6 -99 -97.3 ...
 $ y    : num [1:381] 29.7 28.8 27.6 26.4 25.9 ...
 $ range: num [1:4] -124.7 -67 25.1 49.4
 $ names: chr [1:10] "main" "martha's vineyard" "nantucket island" "manhattan" ...
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "map"
```

Yet, the function map2SpatialLines is able to obtain each territory (10 Lines objects in this case):

```
> str(wrld_sp, max.level=3)
Formal class 'SpatialLines' [package "sp"] with 3 slots
  ..@ lines      :List of 10
  .. ..$ :Formal class 'Lines' [package "sp"] with 2 slots
  .. ..$ :Formal class 'Lines' [package "sp"] with 2 slots
  .. ..$ :Formal class 'Lines' [package "sp"] with 2 slots
  .. ..$ :Formal class 'Lines' [package "sp"] with 2 slots
  .. ..$ :Formal class 'Lines' [package "sp"] with 2 slots
  .. ..$ :Formal class 'Lines' [package "sp"] with 2 slots
  .. ..$ :Formal class 'Lines' [package "sp"] with 2 slots
  .. ..$ :Formal class 'Lines' [package "sp"] with 2 slots
  .. ..$ :Formal class 'Lines' [package "sp"] with 2 slots
  .. ..$ :Formal class 'Lines' [package "sp"] with 2 slots
  ..@ bbox       : num [1:2, 1:2] -124.7 25.2 -67.1 49.4
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..@ proj4string:Formal class 'CRS' [package "sp"] with 1 slots
```

How does it do that? The reason I ask this is because I'd like to obtain the coordinates of a given territory as a polygon or as a line object in Python.

Comment: which(is.na(usa$x)). it is using NA as references for split isn't it?

Comment: Oh... let me check that :-)

Comment: It seems you're absolutely right!

Comment: it can be built manually taking these sequences. `no_nas <- rle(is.na(usa$x))$lengths`; `no_nas[no_nas != 1]`

Comment: Use the source:  maptools::map2SpatialLines and in particular  maptools:::.NAmat2xyList

Comment: @mdsumner Nice tip. I originally had downloaded the source, but as you see, the issue was so straightforward that the source is not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to take the same data structure

```
usadf <- data.frame(usa$x, usa$y)
usa_l <- split(usadf, cumsum(is.na(usa$x)))
with(usa_l$'0', plot(usa.x, usa.y, type = 'l'))
```

[image: simple plot]

Comment: Very clever use of cumsum. Thanks!